# How do I increase enemy's speed every time level increases?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a very long code set up, and I know there should be an easier way, but I can't seem to find it. I want the enemies to increase speed every level by .5. How can I do this?

```
 function makeEnemies():void
 {
var chance:Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 150);
if (chance <=  + level)
{


    tempEnemy = new Enemy();
    tempEnemy.speed = 2
    //Math.random(); gets a random number from 0.0-1.0
    tempEnemy.x = Math.round(Math.random() * 1000);
    addChild(tempEnemy);
    enemies.push(tempEnemy);
    if (level == 2)
    {
        tempEnemy.speed = 3
    }
    if (level == 3)
                    tempEnemy.speed = 4
            }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
var enemyBaseSpeed:int = 2;
var speedLevelInc:Number = 0.5;
```

then later:

```
tempEnemy.speed = enemyBaseSpeed + ((level - 1) * speedLevelInc);
```

(Though you sample code shows the speed increasing by 1 per level)